# How to store distance values with labels into a matrix of distances?

Tags: python, matrix, distance-matrix

I am trying to store the distances between all given documents into a matrix of distances.

This is my code:

```
    dists = [] #a matrix of distances
    i=0
    for row in self.matrix:
        current_row = row
        document_distances = []
        # build list with possibilities for every document in labels
        for label in self.labels:
            document_distances.append((1 - self.row_distance(current_row, label), label))

        dists[i] = document_distances #[(0.22529600444665132, 'Doc1'), (0.22952074233187614, 'Doc2'), (0.289625872768411, 'Doc3'), ...]
        i += 1
    print(dists)
```

But after running the code I get the following error:

`IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Can anyone please tell me what should I change so that my code would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
dists[i] = document_distances
```

Do this:

```
dists.append(document_distances)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some very wierd statements: you iterate over the `row`, and then assign it to the `current_row`, etc. Furthermore you keep track of some counter. These are all not necessary.

The best way is probably using *list comprehension*:

```
dists = [(1 - self.row_distance(row, label), label)
             for row in self.matrix
             for label in self.labels]
```

this replaces all the code.

Or if you really want procedural code, you can use `append`:

```
dists = [] #a matrix of distances

for row in self.matrix:
    document_distances = []
    for label in self.labels:
        document_distances.append((1 - self.row_distance(current_row, label), label))

    dists.append(document_distances)
print(dists)
```